# using "onclick" with radio button in appengine

Tags: html, google-app-engine, radio-button, onclick

Here's a code snippet. . .

```
<form name="FinalAccept" method="get"><br>

<input type="radio" name="YesNo" value="Yes" onclick="/accept"> Yes<br>

<input type="radio" name="YesNo" value="No" onclick="/accept"> No<br>
```

Clearly, what I'm trying to do is call the routine linked to /accept when the user clicks on the radio button.

I know the routine is working because I call the same routine from another place in the program.

I'm trying to run it locally using google appserver. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

If you want to submit the entire form when the user clicks on a radio button, then try this:

```
<form name="FinalAccept" method="get" action="accept"><br>
<input type="radio" name="YesNo" value="Yes" onclick="this.form.submit();"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="YesNo" value="No" onclick="this.form.submit();"> No<br>
</form>
```

Plus, if you want to make your UI a little more user friendly, change it to this:

```
<form name="FinalAccept" method="get" action="accept"><br>
<input id="rYes" type="radio" name="YesNo" value="Yes" onclick="this.form.submit();">
<label for="rYes">Yes</label><br>
<input id="rNo" type="radio" name="YesNo" value="No" onclick="this.form.submit();">
<label for="rNo">No</label><br>
</form>
```

This will make the text "Yes" and "No" as clickable labels for their radio buttons.  The user can click the label to select the radio button.

Answer (score 3):

Your onClick event is expecting some javascript code:

```
onclick="SomeJavaScriptCode"
```

More here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onClick.asp

So, you should be doing something like this:

```
onClick="myfunction('my value');"
```

EDIT: It looks like you want to go to a URL when the user clicks either "yes" or "no".  To do that, you can try this little bit of javascript code:

```
onClick="location.href='http://www.example.com/accept';"
onClick="location.href='http://www.example.com/decline';"
```

Now, if you want to submit the form automatically when the user clicks either "yes" or "no", then do what Benry suggests:

```
onClick="this.form.submit();"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: where do you define that function? 

even if I put in nonsense, it doesn't produce an error. It's like it never gets called. 

is there a way to make an onclick call a cgi script? I'm not using javascript for this.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably thinking of action= for the form element. onClick would just fire a javascript function.